# JBOSS java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jboss, classloader

We have been using JBOSS-4.2.1 as our application  server .

I am trying to load a class (com.sting.ui.saas.reporting.ReportExecutor) . The fully qualified path of this class has been externalized and written in the properties file. This properties file is kept in /bin/properties directory of JBOSS

I am getting the exception

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for:   com.sting.ui.saas.reporting.ReportExecutor
     at org.jboss.mx.loading.LoadMgr3.beginLoadTask(LoadMgr3.java:212)
     at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:514)
     at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:408)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)**

The class is present in /WEB_INF/com/sting/ui/saas/reporting/ReportExecutor.class.

In my properties file I have written -
report.executor.class=com.sting.ui.saas.reporting.ReportExecutor

The properties directory itself is added to the classpath from run.bat file.

Answer (score 0):

I think WEB-INF is not valid place for classes. Change its place to WEB-INF/classes directory.. Or jar that class , and put the jar file to WEB-INF/lib directory..

Comment: Sorry I misspelled , it was web-inf directory. However I tried making all the changes suggested above, but unfortunately the result is same. I have a strong doubt - do I have to add it to the classpath  somewhere else ?